# Can I limit the notification noise to one device when I get a message?

Tags: notifications, messages, macos

I have a few Apple products: MacBook, iPhone, iPad. When someone sends me a text message, and the entire room starts dinging as all three devices tell me I got a message.

Is there an easy way to say, in effect, "I'm at my laptop, just tell me there."

Answer (score 1):

Pick it up on one, the others go silent.

Just checking the lock screen on an iDevice is not sufficient, you need to swipe & open.
On a Mac, bringing Messages to the front will do it.

Comment: I don't mean all three devices ding repeatedly. I get 3 noises. But even that sounds ridiculous. Using Messages on OS X doesn't seem to stop the others from making noises.

Comment: Whichever device you used last will get the notification first, the others will wait about a minute before dinging. Pick up one, the others won't ding. I do it all day, every day... middle of a conversation on my Mac, I'm busy in another app & I just nod at the notification & think, 'yeah, cool' ...If I don't bring it to the front, everything else dings like crazy a minute later.

Comment: Clarification - if I'm on the Mac I tend not to care about floating notifications. The Mac doesn't 'ding' anyway, so I've never had the need to stop the notification if I have already picked up the message on my phone, so my answer is really only to stop the iDevices dinging if you pick up on the Mac. It *may* need the actual chat-bar to be clicked, I haven't been that fastidious in my testing, usually if I pick up on the Mac, I'm in the chat-bar ready to answer anyway.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I'll get someone to test this with me and be back later.